# How to change column element based on value change in other column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data:

```
1   2   1           
2   3   1           
3   4   1           
4   5   1           
5   6   2           
6   7   2           
7   8   2                       
9   10  3           
10  11  3
```

..and I want to change an element of the second column based on a change of value of the third column, to obtain this:

```
1   2   1           
2   3   1           
3   4   1           
4   1   1           
5   6   2           
6   7   2           
7   5   2                       
9   10  3           
10  9   3
```

So before the value in the third column changes, I want to replace the second column element of the same row with the first element of the first column that has the same third column value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses `rle` and `cumsum` to determine the indices of the elements that need updating in column 2.

```r
# Create data frame
df <- read.table(text = "1   2   1           
2   3   1           
3   4   1           
4   5   1           
5   6   2           
6   7   2           
7   8   2                       
9   10  3           
10  11  3    ", header = FALSE)

# Create index
ind <- cumsum(rle(df$V3)$lengths) 

# Update data frame
df[ind, 2] <- df[head(c(1, ind + 1), length(ind)), 1]

# Print result
print(df)
#>   V1 V2 V3
#> 1  1  2  1
#> 2  2  3  1
#> 3  3  4  1
#> 4  4  1  1
#> 5  5  6  2
#> 6  6  7  2
#> 7  7  5  2
#> 8  9 10  3
#> 9 10  9  3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using the `split`, `unsplit`, and `lapply` functions. We replace the last value in the second column with the first value in the first column for each group of `V3` values. The `split` function takes the `data.frame` and turns it into a list of data.

```
unsplit(lapply(split(dat, dat$V3), 
               FUN = function(d) {d[nrow(d), 2] <- d[1,1]; d}))

  V1 V2 V3
1  1  2  1
2  2  3  1
3  3  4  1
4  4  1  1
5  5  6  2
6  6  7  2
7  7  5  2
8  9 10  3
9 10  9  3
```

Answer (score 0):

One option with `rleid` from `data.table`.  After converting to `data.table` (`setDT(df)`), group by the run-length-id of 'V3', `replace` the last element of 'V2' with the `first` of 'V1' and assign (`:=`) it to 'V2'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, V2 := replace(V2, .N, first(V1)), rleid(V3)]
df
#   V1 V2 V3
#1:  1  2  1
#2:  2  3  1
#3:  3  4  1
#4:  4  1  1
#5:  5  6  2
#6:  6  7  2
#7:  7  5  2
#8:  9 10  3
#9: 10  9  3
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L), V2 = c(2L, 
 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 11L), V3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
   2L, 2L, 3L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L
  ))
```